# How to set selected on option in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am currently struggling with dynamically setting the selected value to one of my options in a reactive form.
I have build an edit modal which should display the current category as option of a select, if I open that edit modal instead of having a blank select. My options are showing fine on selection but if I want to set the value it somehow stays empty (not selected).

Currently my select is build like this

```
<select
      formControlName="categories"
      (change)="selectCategory($event)"
      class="form-select"
      id="categories">
      <option *ngFor="let category of categories"
              [value]="category.id">
        {{category.name}}
      </option>
</select>
```

I also tried building my option like this

```
<option *ngFor="let category of categories"
         [value]="category.id"
         [selected]="category === credential.category">
```

But that didn't work. Also tried checking the .name of the category.

Here is part of my .ts file.

```
public selectCategory(event: Event): void {
    const category: Category | undefined = this.categories.find((category: Category) => {
      return category.id === parseInt((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
    });

    this.credentialEditForm.get('category')?.setValue(category);
}

// called in the components ngOnInit() method
private initForm(): void {
    this.credentialEditForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      category: [this.credential.category, Validators.required],
      categories: this.categories,
    });
}

// called when I open the modal so the current values should be put in
// works on other fields the form has (I just didn't put them in here for the code to be shorter)
private fillFormWithInfo(): void {
    this.credentialEditForm.setValue({
      category: this.credential.category,
      categories: this.credential.category.name,
    });
}
```

I have used category and categories as form fields because if I just used categories and I select an option, the select field will also not display the just selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake. I didn't set my categories field to the id but the name instead. In my html I also set the value of my options to the category Id so obviously it should be set to the id in the code too.

```
private fillFormWithInfo(): void {
    this.credentialEditForm.setValue({
      category: this.credential.category,
      categories: this.credential.category.id,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `patchValue` (see the `stuForm.patchValue` part - `stuCity` is a formControl for dropdown):

```js
this.callApi.GetCities()
       .subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            this.ethnRec = data;
            if (this.cityRecord) {
              this.stutForm.patchValue({
                stuCity: this.cityRecord[0].id
              });
            }
          },
          error: (e) => {
          // ...
```